# when I try to install Flask-bcrypt it throws me error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

Tags: python, ubuntu, flask, bcrypt

When I try to install flask-bcrypt library for my app it is throwing me this error:

creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7

```
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/bcrypt

x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c bcrypt/bcrypt.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/bcrypt/bcrypt.o

x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c bcrypt/bcrypt_pbkdf.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/bcrypt/bcrypt_pbkdf.o

x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c bcrypt/bcrypt_python.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/bcrypt/bcrypt_python.o

bcrypt/bcrypt_python.c:18:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory

 #include "Python.h"
^

compilation terminated.

error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

how to solve it??
-thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sudo apt-get install python-dev

Answer (score 8):

if you find that after installing Python-dev and u having trouble then install the Foreign function interface. thats when i was able to install brypt:

sudo apt-get install libffi-dev

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your configuration you might need to install the `python3-dev` package.

Comment: Having had python-dev and libffi-dev already installed with the error still not disappearing, installing python3-dev worked.

Answer (score 0):

You need `python-dev` package installed to build Python extensions.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention what OS you're using, but you need to have Python-dev installed.

Assuming Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev
```