# When use pip to install flask-bcrypt, one error is :UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe6 in position 49: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip

Today, when I install flask-bcrypt used:

```
pip install flask-bcrypt
```

This error happend:

```
Command /home/sf/python/venv/bin/python2 -c "import setuptools, 
tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-duYRO6/bcrypt/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-hlvpv8-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/sf/python/venv/include/site/python2.7 failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-duYRO6/bcrypt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sf/python/venv/bin/pip", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/sf/python/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 248, in main
    return command.main(cmd_args)
  File "/home/sf/python/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 161, in main
    text = '\n'.join(complete_log)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe6 in position 49: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: What version of pip are you using?

Comment: python2.7, I'm sorry , I had solve this problem, and just want to someone who has the same problem can see my answer.

Comment: Your answer is not a good approach, you should not change the default encoding. `sys.getdefaultencoding()` is ascii for me and I can install the package just fine. https://anonbadger.wordpress.com/2015/06/16/why-sys-setdefaultencoding-will-break-code/

Comment: I try many methods want to solve this problem (like this: http://www.ianbicking.org/illusive-setdefaultencoding.html), but failed. Finally, I change the default encoding, and it was solved. Maybe because of my computer used Chinese.

Answer (score 0):

You could try following

```
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
pip install flask-bcrypt
```

Answer (score -1):

When you type under command to python shell,

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.getdefaultencoding()
```

it will output this:

```
'ascii'
```

So, I modify

```
/etc/python2.7/sitecustomize.py
```

added:

```
import sys
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')
```

Now the defaultencoding change to the:

```
'utf-8'
```

This error was solved, but also had another error:

```
Command /home/sf/python/venv/bin/python2 -c "import setuptools,  
tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-6LgjpC/bcrypt/setup.py';
exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', 
'\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-3qxBJi-record/install-
record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 
/home/sf/python/venv/include/site/python2.7 failed with error code 1 in 
/tmp/pip-build-6LgjpC/bcrypt
Storing debug log for failure in /home/sf/.pip/pip.log
```

You can see this: [when I try to install Flask-bcrypt it throws me error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28363514/when-i-try-to-install-flask-bcrypt-it-throws-me-error-command-x86-64-linux-gnu)

I just install:

```
apt-get install libffi-dev
```

Finally, I succeed to install the flask-bcrypt.